# GRE Expiration Date

Tags: gre

How long is the expiration date of GRE? For example, if I am going to sit for the GRE in January 2015, how long can I use the score for my graduate application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your GRE score is valid for (approximately) 5 years since the [taking of the test](http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/faq).

> **How long are GRE scores valid?**
>
> For tests taken on or after July 1, 2016, scores are reportable for five years following your test date. For example, scores for a test taken on July 3, 2018, are reportable through July 2, 2023.
>
> For tests taken prior to July 1, 2016, scores are reportable for five years following the testing year in which you tested (July 1–June 30). For example, scores for a test taken on May 15, 2016, are reportable through June 30, 2021.

Comment: I heard that the new system changed few years ago, so the validity period also changed. From some seniors, they said the validity period is only 2 years. But I can't find any information online to verify the period. That's why I feel very confusing.

Comment: They did change a few things like the number of sections in the exam and the scoring scale, but the validity period is the same. The only reliable information on this can be found on ETS's website, and according to them it's still 5 years.

Comment: Slight correction: they count their years July-to-June, so if taken in January 2015 it will be valid until June 30, 2020 [(ref here)](http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/)

Comment: Don't some departments require scores that are within the last two years? Or some other length?

Answer (score 4):

It's valid for 5 years, as stated on their official website.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show me the site which states the validity period? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/faq/
Under Scoring and reporting.

Comment: See also https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/scores/.